# How to launch a virtual machine in qcow2 format in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-kvm.qcow2 file which I took from this [site](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo) but I don't know how to play the vm. Could you please give me some hints or introduce me the proper tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
kvm -hda cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-kvm.qcow2 -net nic -net user -m 512
```

I hope it helps you as well.